# Puppet reboot when notifed AND parameter set to true

Tags: if-statement, puppet, reboot

I have a shared puppet reboot block in an init.pp, and also want to have a global parameter of $autorestart which defaults to false so the reboot is globally opt-in.  In a subclass I have some resources such as file_line changing settings that normally won't become effective until a reboot occurs, but these do not set the OS flag that a reboot is required (eg writing to audit.rules or sysctl.conf), so have set these to notify => Reboot[after_run].

I know that some of the subclass functions can take effect with service restarts, but that is not what I am try to do here as for example auditd is a protected service.

I have tried putting the global reboot resource in an 'if $autorestart' block, but then the notify on the subclass resource fails to compile if the global $autorestart is set to false.  I'm trying to keep this as flexble yet simple as possible.

init.pp:

```
Boolean $autorestart = false,
…
  if $autorestart {
    reboot { 'after_run':
      apply   => 'finished',
      timeout => 60,
    }
  }
```

subclass.pp:

```
    file_line { 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6':
      path  => '/etc/sysctl.conf',
      line  => 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1',
      match => '^net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6.*',
      notify => Reboot['after_run'],
    }
```

error

```
Could not find resource 'Reboot[after_run]' in parameter 'notify'
```

I have also tried the puppet-reboot 'onlyif' parameter but this only accepts certain conditions and does not test for the value of a parameter.  https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/reboot#reboot-when-certain-conditions-are-met

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... but then the notify on the subclass resource fails to compile if the global $autorestart is set to false

That problem would be solved by moving the relationship metaparameter inside the conditional, i.e.

```puppet
if $autorestart {
  reboot { 'after_run':
    apply     => 'finished',
    timeout   => 60,
    subscribe => File_line['net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6'], ## ADD THIS
  }
}
```

(And of course remove the notify from your file_line resource.)

Comment: Thanks Alex,  I will try that out.  One issue is that I will have about 2 dozen resources that would have otherwise notified the Reboot.  I gather I can create an array of them in the subscribe, but given there will be so many can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: @xit, I could be misunderstanding but I don't see any difference in complexity between having one reboot resource subscribe to an array of many resources, or having a notify line in each of many resources point back to the reboot? Of course if your only concern is that it will look messy then you could experiment with defining the array of resources in a variable perhaps?

Comment: Will do, and will report on outcome later.  Thanks again.

Comment: Alex, your suggestion works perfectly, thanks.  I did create an array of resources (as a variable) to subscribe to, and was then able to de-dupe by changing it to subscribe to an array of classes, which I didn't know was possible!  Thanks again for your fast response.

Comment: @xit, great, glad you sorted it out.